# ngrx/store initialize Observable @Input

Tags: angular, ngrx

How do I initialize template with @Input property using ngrx/store? When I tested `addCategory` function it works as expected but I wish to display initial state which I declared in reducer on initialization class.

reducer.ts:

```
export interface AppState {
  categoryState: AdminCategory[]
}

export class AdminCategory {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  parentId: number;

  constructor(id: number, name: string, parentId: number) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.parentId = parentId;
  }
}

export const ADD_CATEGORY = 'ADD_CATEGORY';
export const REMOVE_CATEGORY = 'ADD_CATEGORY';

export class AddCategory implements Action {
  readonly type = ADD_CATEGORY;

  constructor(public payload: AdminCategory) { }
}

export class RemoveCategory implements Action {
  readonly type = REMOVE_CATEGORY;

  constructor(public payload: AdminCategory) { }
}

export type CategoryActions = AddCategory | RemoveCategory

export function categoryReducer(state: AdminCategory[] = [new AdminCategory(1, "asd", 0)], action: CategoryActions) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_CATEGORY:
      return [...state, action.payload];
    default: state;
  }
}
```

tree-view.ts:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'categories',
  template: `
     <div *ngFor="let cat of categories | async">
      <ul>
       <li>
         <span (click)="addCategory(cat)">{{cat.name}}</span>
       </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  `
})

export class TreeView implements OnInit {

  @Input() categories: Observable<AdminCategory[]>

  constructor(private store: Store<AppState>, private dialog: MatDialog) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.categories = this.store.select('categoryState');
  }

  addCategory(category: AdminCategory) {
    this.store.dispatch(new AddCategory(category));
  }
}
```

I didn't throws any errors, just nothing happens.

Comment: Why would you initialise the `categories` using both `@Input` and `ngOnInit` ?

Comment: I removed `ngOnInit` and put  `this.categories = this.store.select('categoryState');` to constructor. It doesn't change anything. I just want to display my initial state without any actions provided from user. For now I'm just creating `AdminCategory` in reducer function but we can imagine it is an API call

Comment: Did you try something as simple as `{{ (categories | async) | json }}` ?

Comment: yup, also nothing happens. It looks like only event's dispatched in `addCategory` function works. Then it displays actual store with initial state + `category` which I'm passing to function. It's nice but I need to display initial state at beginning. I tried a lot possible solutions, spent about 15 hours with different work-arounds, late-init, initialState from documentation, some timeouts etc... I'm little disappointed that basic use case is pretty hard to implement for me

Comment: Can you create a minimal stackblitz for your issue ?

Comment: I tried to create one but I got another error... `Type 'Store<AdminCategory[]>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<AdminCategory[]>'.`. Here is the stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tyu8wv

Comment: You created a component with the selector `categories` and used the component in his own template. I don't understand what you want to do.

Comment: Because i need recursion to display nested AdminCategories. There is an function which convert `AdminCategory(id, name, parentId)` to JSON with childrens, then I display this tree in template using recursion

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know what you're getting at, but I think this is similar and is towards what you wanted to achieve:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2fukcm

I assume that you want to be able to unfold the tree on every node. I have a rough idea of what you should do, but I'll let you continue how here and see what you find.

By the way, in your stackblitz, you did not have `<categories></categories>` in app component. Also, your default state is missing 'return':

`export function categoryReducer(state: AdminCategory[], action: CategoryActions) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_CATEGORY:
      return createTreeRecursive([...state, action.payload], 0);
    default: return state;
  }
}`

Comment: Yup I need to be able to add category on each node, thanks for help anyway :)